# iOS Native Image Cropping with image OUTSIDE of UIImagePickerController

Tags: ios, ios7, uiimage, crop

So, if I select an image with the UIImagePicker from the camera or camera roll, before I return to my app, it provides this great cropping feature.

I was hoping that there was a way to call this crop API directly without going through the camera or camera roll. If I have an existing image in an app (for instance a user profile photo) and the user wants to re-crop that image, can I open the crop tool?

I haven't seen anything about calling this crop tool outside of UIImagePicker.

Comment: I'm not looking for third party alternatives for cropping. I wanted to know if I could use Apple's native crop tool without going through UIImagePicker